# Customize Excel Online app formula with a choice list where data are read in a List app

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, app

I have an ExcelSheet application.

I want to restrict the input of a column depending on another application "Custom List".

This in what I want to do: [see link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/sharepoint-lookup-fields). 
Should I switch my app from Excel sheet to Sharepoint Custom List?

How can I do this smartly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you could switch to SharePoint custom list. After you switch to SharePoint custom list, you could create the lookup column to restrict the input of the column depending on another application "Custom List".

You could import the excel sheet to the SharePoint list according to the article below. After importing excel to the list, you could create lookup column in the list.

Load Excel data into a SharePoint 2013 list fast and easy.

http://3sharp.com/blog/load-excel-data-into-a-sharepoint-2013-list-fast-and-easy/